# Let $A_3=\{(1), (123),(132)\}$ be a subset of $S_3$. Determine if $\Bbb Z_2 \times A_3=\{(a,\sigma) \mid a\in \Bbb Z_2, \sigma \in A_3\}$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A_3=\{(1), (123),(132)\}$ be a subset of $S_3$. Determine if the group $$\Bbb Z_2 \times A_3=\{(a,\sigma) \mid a\in \Bbb Z_2, \sigma \in A_3\}$$ is cyclic.

Using $(1,(123))$ it seems that I can generate whole $\Bbb Z_2 \times A_3$ as $$\Bbb Z_2 \times A_3=\{(0,(1)), (0,(123)), (0,(132)), (1,(1)), (1, (123)), (1,(132))\}$$

and $$\begin{align} (1,(123))^0 &= (1,(1)) \\ (1,(123))^1&= (1,(123)) \\ (1,(123))^2 &= (0,(132)) \\ (1,(123))^3 &= (1,(1)) \\ (1,(123))^4 &= (0,(123)) \\ (1,(123))^5 &= (1,(132))  \\ (1,(123))^6&=(0,(1)) \\ (1,(123))^7 &= (1,(123)) \end{align}$$

but is there some other way to determine this than to find one element that generates the whole group? This is not very efficient if I have larger groups.

Comment: You can use the Chinese remainder theorem. Since $A_3=C_3$ and $C_2$ have coprime orders, the group is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_6$.

Comment: If you classify the groups of order 6 you will see that up to isomorphisms they are $S_3$ and the cyclic group of order 6 $\mathbb{Z}_6$. Your group is abelian, because it is a product of abelian groups, then it is not isomorphic to $S_3$, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and so it is cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C_n$ denote a cyclic group of order $n$.
Then the direct product $C_m\times C_n$ is cyclic iff $\gcd(m,n)=1$.
In your case, the groups have order 2 and 3 with $\gcd(2,3)=1$.